# Gather elements from list into lists of lists of equal elements?

Tags: python

I have a list of objects in python, and a compare function that, given two objects, decides whether they should be considered equal.

I want to convert the list of objects to a new list of lists, where each sublist gathers elements that compare equal.

What's a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby? It takes a `key`, rather than `cmp`, function, but is otherwise pretty close.

Comment: Either `groupby`, if the list is already sorted, or a dictionary, mapping elements to list of 'equal' elements. How do you compare? Using `__eq__` magic method, or with some external function?

Comment: @tobias_k an external function

Comment: @jonrsharpe `itertools.groupby` assumes the list is sorted. For example, `[1, 2, 1, 1]` will be grouped as `[[1], [2], [1,1]]`, but I want `[[1,1,1], [2]]`.

Comment: Some more information, please. Is that external function mapping one of your elements to some other value, or does it take two elements and return true if they are equal or false otherwise?

Comment: @becko that is true; is yours not? Rather than ask *"What's a pythonic way to do this?"* why not try implementing it, ask here if you get stuck or ask at [codereview.se] if you get it working but think it could be improved?

Comment: @jonrsharpe My list is not sorted (the objects can be tested for equality, but there is no sensible definition of "less than")

Comment: @tobias_k The compare function takes two elements and returns `True` if they are equal, `False` otherwise.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have a working implementation. But it is quite convoluted, so I decided not to post it. If I improve it  I may post it as an answer tomorrow (which I won't accept, since I expect better suggestions).

Comment: Are your objects hashable?  (Makes life easier if they are.)

Comment: @DSM The objects are strings, but the equality comparator doesn't test for string equality. I have a very domain-specific equality definition here which I can't describe now (so strings differing in their characters may still compare equal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a `compare` function, returning `True` or `False` depending on whether the elements are equal, is not ideal. Basically, you will have to compare each element to some "prototype" from each of the existing groups. Something like this:

```
def group(elements, comp_func):
    groups = {}
    for x in elements:
        for y in groups:
            if comp_func(x, y):
                groups[y].append(x)
                break
        else:
            groups[x] = [x]
    return groups
```

Or a bit shorter (but not faster):

```
def group(elements, comp_func):
    groups = {}
    for x in elements:
        prototype = next((y for y in groups if comp_func(x, y)), x)
        groups.setdefault(prototype, []).append(x)
    return groups
```

Example:

```
>>> def comp_len(o1, o2):
...     return len(o1) == len(o2)
>>> group(["foo", "bar", "blub", "blah", "bonk"], comp_len)
{'foo': ['foo', 'bar'], 'blub': ['blub', 'blah', 'bonk']}
```

---

Using a `key` function, mapping each element to some hashable value, would be better:

```
def group(elements, key_func):
    groups = {}
    for x in elements:
        key = key_func(x)
        if key in groups:
            groups[key].append(x)
        else:
            groups[key] = [x]
    return groups
```

Example:

```
>>> group(["foo", "bar", "blub", "blah", "bonk"], len)
{3: ['foo', 'bar'], 4: ['blub', 'blah', 'bonk']}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use an off-the-shelf set consolidation algorithm (which comes up frequently enough it should be in your toolbox anyhow) and simply use your `compare` function to feed data into it.  That is, we view it as a set-consolidation/connected-components problem, where each object is a node and `compare(x,y) == True` means there's an edge between the nodes.

N.B. I'm assuming transitivity, that `compare(x,y) and compare(x,z)` implies `compare(y,z)`.  If that's not true, you're on your own. :-)

To be concrete:

```
from itertools import combinations

def consolidate(sets):
    # http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation#Python:_Iterative
    setlist = [s for s in sets if s]
    for i, s1 in enumerate(setlist):
        if s1:
            for s2 in setlist[i+1:]:
                intersection = s1.intersection(s2)
                if intersection:
                    s2.update(s1)
                    s1.clear()
                    s1 = s2
    return [s for s in setlist if s]

def groupify(seq, comp_func):
    nodes = [{x} for x in seq]
    edges = [{x,y} for x,y in combinations(seq,2) if comp_func(x,y)]
    return [list(g) for g in consolidate(nodes + edges)]
```

which gives

```
>>> def compare(x,y): return max(x)==max(y)
>>> res = groupify(["aaa","abc","a","cab","e","eaab","h"], compare)
>>> res
[['h'], ['a', 'aaa'], ['cab', 'abc'], ['eaab', 'e']]
```

Admittedly this isn't super-concise, but remember that for me, `consolidate` is simply something I import at this point (because it's so handy), so from my perspective this only takes a few lines.